# Intersection of three files

Tags: linux, bash, rar

I have a poor internet connexion and tried to download three times the same rar archive (> 500 Mo). Each file is corrupted but I hope it is possible to create with the intersection of the three corrupted a fourth one without any corruption.
I'm not comfortable with diff or comm and don't know if it is possible to use it to do what I want.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: First of all you should check if all three files are different from each other. If the files are the same, the original file was already corrupted. Run `cmp 1.rar 2.rar ` and `cmp 2.rar 3.rar`. If there is no output at all, then the files are identical.

Comment: Sorry for not answering your specific question, but you may have more success if you use a restartable download instead - curl and wget both support restart, and will manage making sure you have the whole file in the end for you.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327372/can-i-make-curl-or-wget-restart-if-disconnected https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/wget-resume-broken-download.html

Comment: Given the differences, you'd still have to know which set of bytes is the *correct* set of bytes. If 2 of the three agree over a given section, they are *probably* the correct ones, but not necessarily, and if all three differ, all you can do is guess.

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea by chepner in the comments, here is how I would reconstruct the *probable* original.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FILE1="$1"
FILE2="$2"
FILE3="$3"
RESFILE="$4"

diff_at() {
  POS=$(cmp "$1" "$2" -i $3 | sed 's/,//' | cut -d ' ' -f 5)
  if [ "$POS" == "" ]; then
    POS=$(du -b "$1" "$2" | cut -f 1 | sort | head -n1) # min()
  fi
  echo $POS
}

max() {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then # Degenerate case
    echo ""
  elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then # Base case
    echo $(($1 + 0)) # Strings are interpreted as 0
  else
    V=$1
    shift
    M=$(max $@)
    echo $(($V > $M ? $V : $M))
  fi
}

# Shallow check of arguments
if [ $# -ne 4 ]; then
  echo "Provide three files to compare and a file to write output into."
  exit 1
fi

# If one of them is larger, you cannot compare its (probable) correctness
S1=$(du -b "$FILE1" | cut -f 1)
S2=$(du -b "$FILE2" | cut -f 1)
S3=$(du -b "$FILE3" | cut -f 1)
if [ $S1 -gt $S2 -a $S1 -gt $S3 -o $S2 -gt $S1 -a $S2 -gt $S3 -o $S3 -gt $S2 -a $S3 -gt $S1 ]; then
  echo "$0: Unable to reconstruct original file."
  exit 1
fi
FILESIZE=$(max $S1 $S2 $S3)

# The idea is that of extracting and appending the common part
truncate -s 0 "$RESFILE" # This will overwrite existing output
BIAS=0
while [ $BIAS -lt $FILESIZE ]; do
  I12=$(diff_at "$FILE1" "$FILE2" $BIAS)
  I23=$(diff_at "$FILE2" "$FILE3" $BIAS)
  I31=$(diff_at "$FILE3" "$FILE1" $BIAS)

  # Unreconstructible, aka all of them differ at the same byte
  if [ $I12 -eq $I23 -a $I12 -eq $I31 ]; then
    echo "$0: Unable to reconstruct original file."
    break;
  fi

  # Biggest common part
  MAXBYTE=$(max $I12 $I23 $I31)

  # Exclude the file with wrong byte
  if [ $I12 -eq $MAXBYTE -o $I31 -eq $MAXBYTE ]; then
    tail -c+$(($BIAS + 1)) "$FILE1" | head -c $(($MAXBYTE - 1)) >> "$RESFILE"
  else
    tail -c+$(($BIAS + 1)) "$FILE2" | head -c $(($MAXBYTE - 1)) >> "$RESFILE"
  fi

  # Update position
  BIAS=$(($BIAS + $MAXBYTE - 1))
done
```

In order to handle "guesses" (where all the three bytes at the same position differ), you will need to commit changes to the script.

I reckon there are better choices than the above from many points of view, so please consider it as the *quick and dirty* one.